# Topology on ring of endomorphisms

Tags: general-topology, ring-theory, modules, topological-groups, topological-vector-spaces

Let $R$ be a topological ring, let $M$ be a topological commutative group, and let $R\rightarrow \operatorname{End}(M)$ be a ring homomorphism giving $M$ the structure of a left $R$-module (throughout, $\operatorname{End}$ will refer to endomorphisms in the category of topological groups).

> The objective is to find a topology on $\operatorname{End}(M)$ that has the property that $R\rightarrow \operatorname{End}(M)$ is continuous iff the map $R\times M\rightarrow M$ is continuous.

My first attempt was:

> Declare a net $\lambda \mapsto T_{\lambda}\in \operatorname{End}(M)$ to converge to $T\in \operatorname{End}(M)$ iff for every net $\mu \mapsto v_{\mu}\in V$ converging to $v\in V$, it follows that the net $(\lambda ,\mu )\mapsto T_{\lambda}(v_{\mu})$ converges to $T(v)$.

If this defines a topology, then I believe the topology will have the desired property and even make $\operatorname{End}(M)$ into a topological ring itself.  The question is:

> Does this definition of convergence define a topology?  If not, what is a counter-example?  If not this topology, is there any such topology?  If so, what is it?

Comment: See this: http://mathoverflow.net/a/19288/64302. I think it shouldn't be hard to either verify each of the axiom, or get stuck and come up with a counter example

Comment: @user2520938 It's the axiom on iterated limits I had trouble with.  This most certainly does suggest how to find a counter-example,  but I was unsuccessful.  That said, I spent much more time trying to prove it than find a counter-example.  Perhaps I will try again tomorrow.